# I want to run a scripts on the EC2 instances that are being replaced by the new autoscaling group when code deploy runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I have a database table that has a list of the IP addresses for the active EC2 instances in my autoscaling group. When I perform a code deploy and new instances are brought up I need to delete the IP addresses of the instances going down and add the ip addresses of the instances being brought up with that new autoscaling group.
I have a blue green code deploy environment.

All I am thinking that I need is a way to run a script on the EC2 instance that detects it is being shut down. The script will just run a SQL command looking for its IP address and delete it. It sounds simple but I have looked and it seems as if I have to create a Lambda function and look at lifecycle hooks. Isn't there an easier way?

I also need to keep in mind that this needs to work if autoscaling detects that it needs to add an additional instance because it is over loaded and also when its removes an instance because the workload has now slowed down..

I am a newbie so I am getting lost at some of the more advanced stuff (dumb it down a little for me).

I will be running on this on a Centos AMI.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You need to implement a heartbeat on your EC2. They need to keep posting something to somewhere, at regular intervals. Tunning this is a little complicated. Usually (and if I am in the mood to pay for) I use a Beanstalk with ELB instead of raw EC2s instances, but I am not sure this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

See [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

> Lifecycle hooks enable you to perform custom actions by pausing
>   instances as an Auto Scaling group launches or terminates them. When
>   an instance is paused, it remains in a wait state until either you
>   complete the lifecycle action using the complete-lifecycle-action CLI
>   command or CompleteLifecycleAction API action, or the timeout period
>   ends (one hour by default).